# What tool can I use to manage upstart services?

Tags: upstart

How should I configure upstart runlevels ? Of course I could edit `/etc/init/XX` but that wasn't right way to do this, I think.

Answer (score 10):

yup! you have a tool , of course GUI .

Open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

Type as `BootUP Manager` in unity dash , that will open .

[image]

Comment: `bum` is only for SysV Init, not for Upstart

Answer (score 8):

Technically the `.conf` files in `/etc/init/` are configuration files so you are free to edit them.

In Ubuntu 11.04 and later you can use `.override` files to modify Upstart jobs without modifying the `.conf` file: To modify the job `foo` as defined in `/etc/init/foo.conf` create `/etc/init/foo.override` and put  kin the things you want to change.

Unfortunately the documentation for the `.override` files seems to be a bit poor so I'm not really sure about the details here.

[Upstart Intro, Cookbook and Best Practises](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#override-files) uses an `override` file containing a `manual` stanza to prevent an job from beeing started automatically:

```
echo "manual" >> /etc/init/myjob.override
```

Just copying the `.conf` file into the `.override` file seems to work, too.

Comment: Manually poking the files is the "right" way to manage upstart.

Comment: More details on the `.override` file can be found in archive of [Upstart Blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20110711083629/http://upstart.at/2011/03/11/override-files-in-ubuntu-natty/)