# How to prevent Tor from starting automatically on Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, startup, init.d, tor

How do I stop Tor from starting automatically on startup? It is Ubuntu Server so I don't have any GUI.

Answer (score 23):

This is quite confusing. But generally you can edit `/etc/default/tor` and change `RUN_DAEMON="yes"` to `RUN_DAEMON="no"`. Now Vidalia should start its own tor and tor should not start at startup.

Comment: That doesn't seem confusing to me. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 14):

Small update.
Since 15.04, Ubuntu uses systemd instead of upstart by default so now to disable tor on startup we should run:

```
sudo systemctl disable tor.service
```

Answer (score 5):

You have several options here. For a GUI user I'd suggest using  `bum` (Boot-Up Manager) like this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/183899/236). However you are using a server and at the moment Tor has not moved to upstart, so you can use `update-rc.d` or `rm`.

1. Enter `sudo update-rc.d -f tor remove`. This removes all symlinks and at the next reboot Tor will not start. The [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/2265/236) to "[Chkconfig alternative for Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2263/236)" discusses this.
2. Enter `sudo update-rc.d tor disable`. This changes the start script to a stop script and effectively also disables Tor starting at boot time. The [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/40077/236) to "[how to stop apache2, mysql from starting automatically as computer starts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/40072/236)" discusses this method.
3. As SystemV only uses symbolic links, you can use `rm` to remove these: `sudo rm /etc/rc?.d/S*tor`. This deletes every file in the `rcX.d` subdirectories (`X` stands for a number or S) which starts with the letter `S` (for Start script) and ends with `tor`.
4. The same effect has a combination of `find` and `rm`: `find /etc/rc?.d -type l -name "S*tor" -exec rm {} \;`. This looks specific for symbolic links.